# How to display JSON data in FlatList React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I send request to my API 
and it return response that i convert it to JSON as below

[image]

now i want to display this JSON in FlaList

I'm Trying to do this but it doesn't display anything

```
<FlatList

          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text> {item.Begin} </Text> }
```

Comment: Can you share your `console.log(...)`?

Comment: @lsaac i share it in picture

Comment: That was the result of `console.log`, what I meant is the exact code for `console.log` I need to have a look at your variable

Comment: pressBtn = () => {
var x = this.state.dataSource;
console.log(x); }  @lsaac

Answer (score 0):

you need to put Text tag inside a View Tag and also keyExtractor

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Picker } from 'react-native';

 export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
   this.state = {
    data : [
    {"Begin" : "08:00:00" ,End : "08:10:00"},
    {"Begin" : "08:10:00" ,End : "08:20:00"},
    {"Begin" : "08:20:00" ,End : "08:30:00"},
    {"Begin" : "08:30:00" ,End : "08:40:00"},
    {"Begin" : "08:40:00" ,End : "08:50:00"},
    {"Begin" : "08:50:00" ,End : "08:60:00"},
  ]
  }
}

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.Begin.toString();

render() {

 return (
   <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
   <FlatList
   data={this.state.data}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   renderItem={({item}) => <Text> {item.Begin} </Text> }
   />
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: according to the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist View is not required